# Usage of Linear optimization model

Tags: self-study, optimization, model

Young Energy operates a power plant. The power plant is a coal-fired boiler that produces steam which in turn drives a generator. The company can buy different types of coal, and then mix them to meet the demands placed on it which is fired in the boiler. The table shows the characteristics of the different types of coal are:

[image]

The requirement to be burned in the pan is:

- BTU/lb: 11900,
- content of the ashes max 12,2% and
- max moisture 9,4%.

> How should I implement a linear optimization model in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible formulation of this model is as follows:

The purpose of the optimization problem is to obtain the % of each coal type to mix in order to minimize the cost of the mix without violating any operational constraint.

$i = $ index for coal type (1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = B, 4 = D)

$x_{i} =$ % of coal type $i$ to be included in the mix

$c_{i} =$ cost per pound of coal of type $i$

$b_{i} =$ BTUs per pound of coal of type $i$

$a_{i} =$ % of ashes of coal of type $i$

$m_{i} =$ % of moisture of coal of type $i$

Objective Function: Minimize the cost of a pound of the mix

Min $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{4} c_{i} \cdot x_{i}$

Subject to the following contraints:

- $BTU/lb$ of the mix must be equal to 11,900:

  $\sum_{i=1}^4 b_{i} \cdot x_{i} = 11900$
- Content of ashes of the mix must be less than 12.2%:

  $\sum_{i=1}^4 a_{i} \cdot x{i} \leqslant 12.2\%$
- The percent of moisture of the mix must be less than 9.4%:

  $\sum_{i=1}^4 m_{i} \cdot x{i} \leqslant 9.4\%$
- The percent of each coal in the mix must add up to 100%:

  $\sum_{i=1}^4 x{i} = 100\%$
- Non-negativity constraint:

  $x_{i} \geqslant 0, \forall i$

You can implement the model in R using the Rglpk package or using the Excel Solver Add-in in MS Excel.